# Not able to deploy pyramid application to the heroku running well in local

Tags: python, heroku, pyramid

This is the error I get checking the logs on HEROKU.
[image: Error in the logs]
The documentation of pyramid says "**Create run with the following command.**"
So I create a file named as run.py and saved below codes. I dont know if this is the right way to create a run if not help me with that.
***Here is the line of code in run.py***

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
python setup.py develop
python runapp.py
```

**Here is the runapp.py**

```
import os

from paste.deploy import loadapp
from paste import httpserver

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app = loadapp('config:development.ini', relative_to='.')

    httpserver.serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

**Finally here is the procfile**

```
$ echo "web: ./run" > Procfile
```

Answer (score 0):

The Pyramid Community Cookbook has a [deployment recipe for Heroku](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/deployment/heroku.html), assuming that is what you meant by "the documentation of Pyramid" (it's not official documentation, just a collection of recipes from the community).

In Step 1, make sure that the **four** files you create are done so locally in the root of your project directory.

- `requirements.txt`
- The file you named `run.py` should be named `run`.
- Check that the file named `Procfile` was created and contains not the command to generate `Procfile`, but just the result of the command, specifically:

  ```
  web: ./run
  ```
- `runapp.py`

Comment: still not done. According to error logs H14 , I tried to scale the logs too with heroku ps:scale web=1 but didn't work still same problem

Comment: You have not said what documentation you followed, nor what you have done on your local system. You need to update the question or elaborate further to get more help.